# Left and Right Border of PasswordBox Missing

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am currently designing a login form in WPF Application. I have a TextBox for the email and PasswordBox for the password. But when I run the program the left and right border of the PasswordBox are missing. Please see the attached image.

This is the XAML of the controls.

```
<Window x:Class="Project_CrystalX.LoginWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Project_CrystalX"
    mc:Ignorable="d" ResizeMode="NoResize"
    Title="Project CrystalX" Height="400" Width="350"
    Icon="D:\\Photos\\logo.ico">
<Grid>
    <Image Source="D:\\Photos\\user.png" Width="75" Height="75"
           HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top"
           Margin="0 25 0 0"/>
    <Label HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
           Margin="0 115 0 0" FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontSize="17.5"
           FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="#0b3170">
        Welcome
    </Label>

    <Label HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
           Margin="0 175 0 0" FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontSize="15"
           FontWeight="SemiBold" Foreground="#0b3170">
        User Authentication
    </Label>
    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
             Margin="0 207.5 0 0" Padding="2 2.5 2.5 2" TextAlignment="Center"
             Height="25" Width="240" MaxLength="254" 
             Name="TextboxEmail"></TextBox>
    <PasswordBox HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
             Margin="52,255,52,0" Padding="2 2.5 2.5 2" MaxLength="128"
             Height="25" Width="240" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
             Name="TextboxPassword" />

    <Button Height="30" Width="115" Margin="52,303,0,0"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"
            Name="ButtonLogin">Login</Button>
    <Button Height="30" Width="115" Margin="177,303,0,0"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"
            Name="ButtonExit">Exit</Button>
    <Label HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
           Margin="47 230 0 0" Height="25" FontSize="9" Foreground="Red"
           Name="LabelEmailError">
        Please enter your email address.
    </Label>
    <Label HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
           Margin="47,277,0,0" Height="25" FontSize="9" Foreground="Red"
           Name="LabelPasswordError">
        Please enter your password.
    </Label>

</Grid>
```

Comment: You should probably remove your email from this sample code.

Comment: @Tomsen ok :)) thanks

Comment: It seems you are trying to layout your UI with only Margins, which is a bad idea. Better use a Grid with rows and columns or nested StackPanels or DockPanels.

Comment: @Clemens but they are actually in a Grid, but I've always had problem with the UI. Any topic or thread I can refer to to get some good ideas to design my UI?

Comment: Share the whole xaml code if possible.

Comment: @user2250152 I've shared the whole code.

Comment: You've got far too much going on in terms of setting size / margin / padding for your controls. A basic grid layout will be much easier - e.g. https://www.wpf-tutorial.com/panels/grid-rows-and-columns/

Comment: There are no row or column definitions in your Grid, i.e. all child elements are in a single cell. Please take a look at the online documentation.

Comment: Thanks all so much. I'll take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case change `Margin="52,255,52,0"` to `Margin="0 255 0 0"` for PasswordBox

```
<PasswordBox HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
             Margin="0 255 0 0" Padding="2 2.5 2.5 2" MaxLength="128"
             Height="25" Width="240" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
             Name="TextboxPassword" />
```

But as others suggested, you should use Rows and Columns and not place all elements into one cell.